# How to create a very dynamic and animated UI in android?

Tags: android, user-interface, dynamic

I need to make an android app that has a very dynamic ui. 
For example imagine we have an activity with only one button inside that in center. Then when someone clicks the button. The button converts to edittext. When user enters some text, the editText converts to textview. And then under the textview, two new buttons automatically Appear. This proccess will go on untill user create a binary-tree like structure. I want this kind of UIs.

I Hope you Undrestand My Problem.

My question is, how can i achieve this kind of UIs?
Can you give any suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what the requirements are, are we talking about simple animations like fading out and fading in, maybe some pulsation and then edit text appearance. It depends because it might be enough to use existing tools like using the [ObjectAnimator](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/animation/ObjectAnimator.html) or even xml or you will have to do some fancy stuff as in writing animation code that meets your particular requirements. Apart from that a factor is what versions of Android are you trying to support JellyBean and above or Lollipop and above.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. My goal will be jelybean and above. Your suggestion for using objectAnimator helped me for animating those views. But an importand part left. How can i make ui so that limitless making and removing views on activity depend on user actions. For example making a tree graph like structure without limitations on how many nodes he wants. I want buttons and texts views create automatically and positions in appropriate places. I didn't saw any app that has this kind of ui. I don't know can we make such ui's or not!

Comment: Well from what you are describing the animation that you tried was on a specific number of views and now the next step is to be able to create dynamically views at a certain position on the screen on some user action such as pressing a button. Well, I think here you need to play with the canvas and actually draw programmatically the nodes/views that you want. http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/2d-graphics.html